# How to add build parameters to jenkins multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-2

I would like to add additional build parameters to my jenkins mutibranch pipeline job.

Relevant versions:

- org.jenkins-ci.plugins:script-security:1.19
- org.kohsuke:groovy-sandbox:1.10
- org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-war:2.0
- org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-aggregator:2.0

My Jenkins file:

As you can see the first four lines are supposed to add the build parameter option.

```
import hudson.model.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable;
build.addAction(new ParametersAction(new StringParameterValue("SVN_UPSTREAM", build.getEnvVars()['SVN_REVISION'])));
println "SVN_UPSTREAM:" + build.getEnvVars()['SVN_UPSTREAM'];

node('dockerSlave') {
   stage 'Checkout'
   checkout scm

   def mvnHome = tool 'M3'

   stage 'VersionSet'
   def v = version()
   if (v) {
     echo "Building version ${v}"
   }
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

   stage 'Build'
   sshagent(['601b6ce9-37f7-439a-ac0b-8e368947d98d']) {
      sh 'echo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK' 
      sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean deploy scm:tag"
      step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
   }
}

def version() {
  def matcher = readFile('pom.xml') =~ '<version>(.+)</version>'
  matcher ? matcher[0][1] : null
}
```

Unfortunately i get the following error:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>   Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.lang.Thread
>   currentThread at

Is there a way to add the static method to a whitelist or add a build parameter via a different way?

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.lang.Thread currentThread
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:180)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:177)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:91)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:15)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:2)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

*Update:*

Seems like disabling the sandbox mode is not possible at the moment.

https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207406207-Avoid-script-approvals-with-a-Jenkins-Pipeline-Groovy-script

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `properties` step. Also take a look here at [Stackoverflow: How do I use jenkins pipeline properties step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370810/how-do-i-use-jenkins-pipeline-properties-step). That is my question where I've learned that you need to explicitly add parentheses even though snippet generator doesn't do that.

Example:

```
properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [[$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'myparam', defaultValue: 'default value']]]])
echo "received ${binding.hasVariable('myparam') ? myparam : 'undefined'}"
```

Comment: Will the delcarative syntax also work? ` pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'P_A', defaultValue: 'a', description: 'a')
        string(name: 'P_B', defaultValue: 'b@b.com', description: 'b')
    }`

Comment: Hi Learner, for declarative pipeline, the job parameter syntax is shown in https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters