# How to setup a multiline parametrized cron job in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline

So this is working fine:

```
properties([
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370810/how-do-i-use-jenkins-pipeline-properties-step
    parameters([
        //note here that the default will be the element you have as a first choice in the array
        choice(name: 'environmentName', choices: ['PROD', 'STAGE'], description: 'Choose the environment you want to run automation tests'),
    ]),

    //explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113834/trigger-hourly-build-from-scripted-jenkinsfile
    //recall that ANY change you do here you will need to execute the job once manually for the new cron parameter to be updated, pushing it is not enough
    //minutes, hours, day of month, month, day of week  //H is any first available (here minute) of the hour according to resources
    pipelineTriggers([
       parameterizedCron('*/2 * * * 0-4 %environmentName=STAGE')
    ]),
])
```

However when trying to define it in multiline as explained here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md

then this is NOT working:

```
properties([
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370810/how-do-i-use-jenkins-pipeline-properties-step
    parameters([
        //note here that the default will be the element you have as a first choice in the array
        choice(name: 'environmentName', choices: ['PROD', 'STAGE'], description: 'Choose the environment you want to run automation tests'),
    ]),

    //explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113834/trigger-hourly-build-from-scripted-jenkinsfile
    //recall that ANY change you do here you will need to execute the job once manually for the new cron parameter to be updated, pushing it is not enough
    //minutes, hours, day of month, month, day of week  //H is any first available (here minute) of the hour according to resources
    pipelineTriggers([
        //cron('H 23 * * 0-4') //this works with the DEFAULT parameters
        parameterizedCron { //this is documented here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md
            parameterizedSpecification( '''
                # leave spaces where you want them around the parameters. They'll be trimmed
                #*/2 * * * * %environmentName=STAGE;SomeOtherVariable=Pluto
                #you may repeat multiple configuration if you want
                */2 * * * 0-4 %environmentName=STAGE
            ''' )
        }
    ]),
])
```

and upon execution of the jenkins job the exception received is this one:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.parameterizedscheduler.ParameterizedTimerTrigger.parameterizedSpecification expects class java.lang.String but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2
```

So it seems that the `parameterizedSpecification` method is found ok and it complains only for the passed parameter but the passed parameter is only a multiline string.
Is this an issue of proper Groovy syntax or anything else? Not sure at all. We need your help

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the answer is as simple as this:

```
parameterizedCron( '''
          */2 * * * 0-4 %environmentName=STAGE
          */3 * * * 0-4 %environmentName=PROD
        ''' )
```

meaning that you don't need the more complex form of including the `parameterizedSpecification`

without exactly understanding why this worked