# Jenkins how to pass cron string as parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Is it possible to pass parameters as a string, something like below?

```
properties([
cronStr = "/3 * * * *"
pipelineTriggers([cron(cronStr)]),
])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup a multiline parametrized cron job in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789810/how-to-setup-a-multiline-parametrized-cron-job-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @K.B., the below worked for me. Issue with scope of the variable.

```
def cronStr = "/3 * * * *" 
properties([ 
pipelineTriggers([cron(cronStr)]), 
])
```